# PHP / JS Login System

Tags: javascript, php, authentication

so I have a self written php web service for an app.

Now I want to do the same with the web. But I struggle with the login.

I need to call 2 functions of the web service. One to get a login token another one to verify that and request a access token.

So I call them with javascript:

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']))
        {
?>
            <script>
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open("POST", "http://webservice.com/requestLoginToken", false);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhttp.send(<?php echo "'email=" . urlencode($_POST['email']) . "'"?>);
                if(xhttp.status == 401)
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                else 
                {
                    var loginToken = xhttp.responseText;
                    var pwHash = loginToken + <?php echo "'" . sha1($_POST['password']) . "'" ?>;
                    pwHash = sha1(pwHash);
                    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.open("POST", "http://webservice.com/authenticate", false);
                    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xhttp.send("loginToken=" + loginToken + "&publicHash=" + pwHash);
                    if(!xhttp.status == 200)
                        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                    else 
                    {
                       var accesstoken = xhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
            </script>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

So now I have the access token. But how can I set this now as a session variable of $_SESSION?

Or what is the best way so save this access token during the stay?

I need this token whenever I call the API.

Comment: When you get the token, send it to your PHP code through an ajax call. However, take care about the way that you do it, because it can be a security risk if you do it in the wrong way. In the other side, if it is not strictly need in your application to do it with javascript, I suggest you to handle the whole login process with PHP, using curl for instance.

Comment: CURL was the trick I searched! Works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you should definitely consider using a proper framework or library, even for something that small. *Code Igniter* as far I remember is easy to get started with.

For instance, that line: `urlencode($_POST['email'])` is a big security issue, allowing XSS attacks.

Now, back to your question. What you need is to set a session cookie, then the browser will take care of it for you. Setting a cookie from JS is considered a bad practice (as it prevents using `HttpOnly` cookies, a recommended security flag), the easiest would be that the server answering to the login AJAX call set a cookie on the response.
That cookie will be issued to any subsequent calls to the same server. Again, if you use a proper framework, all the authentication stuff will be handled for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestions. Yeah, it would be much better to do so. I will do this in the next time.